# How to insert null values to a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a notification table that has the following columns:

1. `notification_id` - PK
2. `message_id` - FK
3. `comment_id` - FK

If I create a message, it should insert into the `notification table` the `message_id` and a null value for `comment_id`

And likewise if I tried to create a comment, it should insert into the `notification table` the `comment_id` and a null value for `message_id`

But it doesn't work, so I'm confused as to how am I going to accomplish this because it would seem to be a waste if I created two tables named `message_notification table` and `comment_notification table`.

Comment: It is not possible to insert a `null` value in a foreign key field.

Comment: Hmmm, any suggestions on another way to accomplish what I'm doing?

Comment: John Stevenson is wrong - If you setup your foreign key column to allow nulls, you can indeed have nulls. Obviously the PK in the related table has to not allow NULLs.

Comment: Incredible, I checked the null boxes and now I can insert null vales, I would up your answer but I can't seem to up it. But I would just like to let you and everyone know it worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key is mostly created to match with primary key with another specified table. So logically it is not accepting NULL values. Off course it can be made to accept NULL values. (http://mysqlrockstar.blogspot.in/)

CREATE TABLE notification_table
(
   notification_id INT NOT NULL,
   message_id INT NULL,
   comment_id INT NULL
);

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick or at least the idea behind it. What I did was to check the null boxes when changing the columns. But overall this was spot on.